# Spree version Up-gradation from 1.1 to 2.1 - Issues && Best Practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

Can any one teach/guide me the best approach for upgradation of spree 1.1 to 2.1 version If any one have idea?

Actually I am looking to upgrade spree version from 1.1 to 2.1 where I am getting the more dependency errors why because I have used more spree extentions which are supportable to spree 1.1.

I am looking for compatible version of these extensions with spree 2.1.

I don't find any below extentions compatible versions with Spree 2.1.

- spree_essentials
- spree_essentials_blog
- spree_essentials_cms
- spree_social
- spree_address_book

  As per my review, Its big deal to upgrade spree along with above extensions..

Please any one share me your idea on it If you thought/find any compatible version of above extensions with latest spree 2.1 ver.

I am eagerly waiting for your reply/help.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You may have better luck in the Spree mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/spree-user .  After I posted this, I notice that you cross-posted this in both places.  Carry on :)

Answer (score 0):

One important thing is to upgrade to each major/minor release along the way.  In your case you'll need to go:

1.1 -> 1.2 -> 1.3 -> 2.0 -> 2.1

You can upgrade to the latest patch release for each minor version, or upgrade to the 'x-x-stable branch on Spree's github (for example 1-2-stable).

Then you're correct that you're going to have to deal with all of the customizations that you've made.  2.1 is a very new release.  It also makes a significant change moving from Rails 3.2.x to Rails 4.x.  You'll need to follow a Rails 3->4 migration guide for your application in order to get your application working in Rails 4 (outside of Spree).

Because Spree 2.1 is so new, and you have to upgrade each release along the way, I'd probably recommend that you stop at 2.0 for now.  You're more likely to find extensions that work with 2.0.  Remember to check Github forks for people who have already upgraded the support Spree version of those extensions.

Comment: Also don't forget to read this guide from Stefan Wrobel (https://gist.github.com/swrobel/6343549) on things that he encountered moving from Spree 1.3 to 2.0.4